# Problema con lista dentro de Dictionary en C#

Tags: c#, lista, unity3d

Tengo lo siguiente :

```
dic = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>;
```

Pero cuando hago `dic.Add` los valores por parámetro que espera son un `string` y un `List<int>`, pero para una misma `key` (`string`) quiero agregar otro `int` a la lista, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola Elpingui8, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, me parece que tu pregunta es un tanto ambigua, ¿podrías poner ejemplos de código en donde te genera el error así como el error que te muestra el IDE?

Comment: No creo que puedas hacerlo con un tipo `Dictionary`, aunque creo recordar que existe un tipo `Lookup`  que sí podrías usar para hacer eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que al querer agregar un valor de tipo `int` la lista realmente lo que estás haciendo es agregar una nueva entrada al diccionario, por lo tanto te marca el error de la llave duplicada en el diccionario, para agregar un valor a la lista, primero debes encontrar la llave en el diccionario y luego, agregar el valor a la lista. Usando Linq puedes agregar valores a la lista de esta forma:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

dic.Add("1", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
dic.Add("2", new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 });
dic.Add("3", new List<int> { 7, 8, 9 });

dic.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == "1").Value.Add(10);
dic.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == "1").Value.Add(11);
dic.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == "1").Value.Add(12);

foreach(var item in dic){
    Console.WriteLine("Llave string: " + item.Key);

    foreach (var valuesList in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valores en lista: " + valuesList.ToString());
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/DRHE44472)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha servido para añadir elementos a la lista que se encuentra dentro del dictionary.. pero como puedo hacer para detectar un elemento de la lista de int puntual para eliminarlo.. agradecería mucho si ayuda!!

Comment: Sigue la misma lógica que el diccionario para que primero busques el `INT `que deseas eliminar, realiza algunos intentos y si no lo logras, realiza una nueva pregunta, mostrando tus avances y con gusto te ayudamos :D @Elpingui8

Comment: Gracias Flxr! Tuve que crear una nueva pregunta ya que estuve probando bastante y no puedo hacerlo.. hay algo que debo estar haciendo mal

Answer (score 0):

Bien puedes usar LINQ como *Flxtr* expuso arriba, o crear una clase que te permita hacerlo de forma sencilla:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Custom myCustom = new Custom(); //Instancias tu propio dic

        myCustom.Add("Hola", 10); //Agregas de a uno
        myCustom.Add("Hola", 30, 50, 10); //O agregas de a muchos

        var values = myCustom.Dic["Hola"]; //Casual, accediento a tus valores...
    }
}

public class Custom
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> Dic { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

    public void Add(string str, params int[] pms)
    {
        if (Dic.Count > 0)
            if (!Dic.ContainsKey(str))
                Dic.Add(str, pms.ToList());
            else
            {
                var temp = Dic[str];

                Dic.Remove(str);
                Dic.Add(str, temp.Concat(pms).ToList());
            }
        else Dic.Add(str, pms.ToList());
    }
}
```