# ¿Cómo eliminar un valor de una lista que está en un diccionario en C#?

Tags: c#, lista, unity

Tengo ese diccionario:

```
dic = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>;
```

Al cual pude agregarle elementos (`int`) individualmente a cada `Key` (`string`), pero lo que realmente no estoy pudiendo hacer es eliminar con `Remove` un elemento puntual de la lista de enteros.

Comment: Sería bueno que pongas el código que utilizas para hacer el remove y el error que te da

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo el hilo de la [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46274/problema-con-lista-dentro-de-dictionary-en-c),la cuestión ahora sería que en lugar de agregar un nuevo valor entero a la lista, ahora lo tenemos que remover, la lógica es la misma, cuando lo quieras remover utiliza:

```
dic.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key == "1").Value.Remove(11);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/BYF64430)</kbd>

Comment: Ok pero ahí el 11 sería el índice de la lista o el valor a eliminar? Allí está el problema que tengo..

Comment: El 11 corresponde al valor entero de la lista, y que está asociado al `key = "1"` del diccionario.

Comment: Excelente gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Al contario, a ti :)

Comment: Una última consulta.. que sucede si tengo varios elementos de la lista con el mismo valor y quiero borrar solo uno

Comment: Según el código que tenemos y que hemos venido manejando, al utilizar el método `FirstOrDefault` solo se eliminará un valor de la lista de enteros en caso de que se tengas repetidos, si deseas que se eliminen todos debemos cambiar un poco la lógica

Comment: Exacto! Justo lo había comprobado con unas pruebas y es lo que necesitaba! Muchas gracias Flxtr

Comment: A la orden amigo :D

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de eliminar enteros del diccionario sería la siguiente:

```
dict[*clave string para la entrada que deseas borrar*]
    .Remove(*valor de la lista a borrar*);
```

Ejemplo:

```
dict["Primos"].Remove(4);
```

Ejemplo borrando la primera posición:

```
dict["Primos"].RemoveAt(0);
```